What does a linkage register actually do in sic
This is a sic assembler program where a reading and writing is done:

Here the value in linkage register is stored in RETADR.but I don't see it using in RSUB call ...so if not for subroutine call why would we want to store the value and how do subroutine call work in sic

" I don't see it using in RSUB" look closer. It is on line 70 and 75.

What I mean is in subroutine...how do we return from the subroutine without using it

RSUB automatically uses the current value of the link register, it does not have to be referenced explicitly in case that's what you are expecting.

For one, let's note that FIRST is a subroutine, probably invoked by some operating system / system loader.  FIRST has code lines ranged from 10 to 75, then some data from 80 to 105.
Also, let's note that FIRST calls another subroutine, RDREC, which has code lines from 125 to 180, with data at 185 to 190.
Next, let's point out that the JSUB instruction not only branches to the target label, but also sets the L register by capturing the prior (incremented) PC, setting L with an address to return, i.e. the next instruction after the JSUB.
And that the RSUB instruction copies the L register contents into the PC.
Thus, a JSUB to a label is effectively the control transfer to make a call (while capturing the address of the next instruction into L), and the RSUB is the control transfer to perform subroutine return.  Thus, a callee can return to whomever called it, without a direct (i.e. labeled) branch target.
In subroutine invocation, we should think of the L register as a parameter to the subroutine that it will ultimately use in returning to its caller.  These linkage and control transfers are largely invisible to C code, but visible in most all assembly languages / machine codes.
Here are RTL definitions of what these two instructions do:
Mnemonic      Format  Opcode  Effect                               Notes
------------  ------  ------  -----------------------------------  ------
JSUB m         3/4      48    L <-- (PC); PC <-- m
RSUB           3/4      4C    PC <-- (L)

When FIRST is called by the system loader (not shown) the L register holds a return address.  But, because FIRST itself makes another function call, the L register is necessarily repurposed for that new call.  However, L is in use already, holding a later-needed value.  Thus, FIRST stores the value in L into memory, then makes the subroutine call, then reloads L from that memory location, and then returns to the system loader.  L is used for two different calls, one from the system loader to FIRST, and one from FIRST to RDREC.
You may note that RDREC does not store L.  This is because it is unnecessary as RDREC does not modify L (because, for one, it does not call another function).  Because it doesn't modify L, it neither needs to store it nor reload it — it can use RSUB directly on the caller-provided L value.

Let me just add that while this approach was common back in the day, storing something like L in static memory (here with label RETADR): this approach won't work in some scenarios, such as recursion, reentrancy, multithreading.  For this reason, processor architectures moved away from global/static memory areas, toward stackable areas of local memory, even though those tend to require some additional processor resources like a stack pointer register.
